# Plotting data over time with different start/end and frequency

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2, plot

**I'm a new to data science and I'm looking for an approach to plot data over time and i don't know where to start**.

Right now I have a SQLlite database containing datapoints consisting of a name, a timestamp
and a value and it looks like this
[image]

*I can change this database to a csv file my shiny app if necessary*

My goal is to plot the values by "name" over time(the one in the timestamps)
the problem I have is that the values have a different frequency and a different start/end time.

I'm looking for an approach in either R or Python but I Prefer R

i experimented with the R plot function but i get errors like:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Is there a library or approach that can help me achieve this goal?

Comment: If your data was in a data frame in R called `df`, make sure the `timeStamp` column is in POSIXct format and the `value` column is definitely numeric. The you can do `ggplot(df, aes(timeStamp, value, color = name)) + geom_line()`

Comment: @AllenCameron my shiny plot output stays empty, i made sure the timestamp column is in POSIXct format and typeof(myDataFrame$timestamp) gave back "double" am I missing something?

Comment: no, `typeof` _should be_ "double" for POSIXct (we rarely use `typeof` in R, since method dispatch depends on _class_, which is not always the same as `typeof`). You'd really need to show us a reproducible example (pictures are no use to us since we can't copy-paste these into our console). Could you perhaps try `dput(df)`, where `df` is the name of your actual data frame? You can copy-paste the result in a code block in your question, so that we can reproduce your data in our consoles? Thanks

Comment: upon further testing i noticed that this line DOES output a plot in regular Rstudio but not in shiny plotoutput